# Jquery load function behavior on reload

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

In my index.php I load a page content with jquery load function.
To access the elements just loaded I use the load callback function.

This is my scenario

index.php

```
<html>..
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

<div id="load-page"></div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="reload">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Reload
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="selectAll">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Select All
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="add">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add
</button>
```

loaded-page.php

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chbox[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="chbox[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="chbox[]" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="chbox[]" value="4" />
```

script.js

```
$(function() {

    var loadPage = function () {

        $('#load-page').load('loaded-page.php', function() {

            $('#selectAll').on('click', function(){
                $('input[name="chbox[]"]').prop('checked', true);
                console.log($(this).html());
            });

            $('#reload').on('click', function(){
                loadPage();
            });

            $('#add').on('click', function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: add.php,
                    success: function(data) {
                        loadPage();
                    }
                });
            });

        });
    }

    loadPage(); // Load page when DOM ready

});
```

Everything seemed to work fine, but I noticed that at the startup (first load), if I click the "Select All" button the console display

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-checked"></span> Select All
```

After first load if I re-load (reload or add) and then I click "Select All" button the console display

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span> Select All
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span> Select All
```

if I still re-load (reload or add) and then I click "Select All" button the console display

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span> Select All
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span> Select All
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span> Select All
```

and so on..

How could I do? Thank You

Comment: `#selectAll` etc... aren't part of loaded content as i can see it, so unwrap it from `load()` complete callback

Comment: @A.Wolff - I'm sorry but how can do it? Thanks

Comment: @mohamedrias - With $.Ajax my functions (selectAll /add/reload) must be putted in complete callback? Thanks